# Serve static files from directory depending on http referrer inside of nginx

Tags: nginx, http-headers, request, static-files

My server hosts images, but the content of images have to be different for the same link and have to deepens on http referrer.

```
For example: Website 1 load image website1.jpg from www.example.com/123123/img.jpg
             Website 2 load image website2.jpg from www.example.com/123123/img.jpg
```

How can i manage do it using `NGINX` configuration?

UPDATE:
I give you guys more details about whole idea:

Images loads on the pages:

```
www.not_my_website.com/123123/
www.not_my_website.com/456456/
www.not_my_website.com/686667/
```

I can't access to this site, but there can be images from my site.

```
<img src="www.example.com/123123/img.jpg"></img>
```

I need serve others images with the same htlm code based on page ID www.not_my_website.com/ID/).

Thanks for help.

Comment: It's really bad idea.

Comment: How on earth did you come up with such an idea ?

Comment: I am not asking is good or not idea. I am asking how.
Lucas - ask person who created problem which i must solve :)

Comment: @user2721435 We are not headless chickens. When someone is completely mistaken, the right way to deal with his question is to show why he's wrong, not by providing a wobbly solution.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to implement hotlink protection. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's absurd.  You can't do that at the configuration level and there are innumerable reasons it is a horrible idea.

The only way to effect something like that would be to write a CGI application that fetches them based on whatever you want.  But, you really should explain why it's a bad idea to break convention like this - imagine the effect of caching proxies, browser caches, and all the other things that assume image content from a GET request is invariant across referrer changes.  Also this is totally unsuitable for use as an authorization mechanism since the header can trivially be forged, so I hope that isn't your reasoning.